# how to publish a docker container port to one of the random available port in the host

Tags: docker, containers

I tried to do the following:

```
docker run --expose 8765 --publish-all -it nginx
```

But this also exposes `80` along with port `8765`

```
[root@centos7]# docker port f4b608998815
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:49156
80/tcp -> :::49156
8765/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:49155
8765/tcp -> :::49155
```

How to publish port `8765` to one of the random available ports in the host without specifying where to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nginx` base image already declares `EXPOSE 80` and there's no way to un-expose a port, so if you use the `docker run -P` or `--publish-all` option to publish every exposed port, it will always be published alongside your manually-exposed port.

You can use the lowercase `docker run -p` option with only a single port number to publish that port on an arbitrary host port instead:

```sh
docker run -p 8765 -d nginx
```

Since Docker containers internally won't have port conflicts with each other, you may want to just use the default HTTP port 80, matching the standard Nginx config.  The `--expose --publish-all` combination is pretty much the only actual effect of `docker run --expose`, and you can get the same thing with `--port`; you pretty much never need the `docker run --expose` option.